# Rspec testing association results in failure

Tags: ruby-on-rails, rspec

I'm trying to create "components" for my project and each component belongs to one of four types (Section, Composition, LearningIntentions, or EssentialQuestion). A section is a component and can contain multiple components, but a section cannot contain a section.

But when I run my spec, I get the error `Expected Component to have a has_many association called components (no association called components)`. But it works when I move the spec from section_spec.rb to component_spec.rb. What is happening here?

component.rb (model):

```
class Component < ApplicationRecord

  # == Constants =============================
  TYPES = %w( Section Composition LearningIntentions EssentialQuestion )

  # == Associations ==========================
  belongs_to :project
  belongs_to :section,
    class_name: 'Component',
    foreign_key: :section_id,
    optional: true

  # # == Validations ===========================
  validates :type,
    presence: true,
    inclusion: { in: TYPES }

end
```

section.rb (model):

```
class Section < Component

  # == Associations ==========================
  has_many :components,
    class_name: 'Component',
    foreign_key: :section_id

  # == Validations ===========================
  validates :section_id, presence: false

end
```

section_spec.rb:

```
RSpec.describe Section, type: :model do
  subject! { build(:component, :section) }

  # == Associations ==========================
  it { is_expected.to have_many(:components) }

end
```

Answer (score 0):

#### Reason for failed test

> But it works when I move the spec from section_spec.rb to component_spec.rb

The location of your rspec is not the cause of failure here, as it looks to me. What you are doing wrong is, assigning a `Component` instance in your *section_spec.rb* as the `subject` and so, it expects the association `:components` to be present on that `Component` instance.

#### Fix for failed test

Change the code to below and see if it works:

```
RSpec.describe Section, type: :model do
  subject { build(:section) }
  it { is_expected.to have_many(:components) }
end
```

#### Using traits in factory

If you want to build a `Section` instance with components assigned to it, then define a [`trait`](https://www.rubydoc.info/gems/factory_bot/file/GETTING_STARTED.md#Traits) and use it as below:

```
# Factory
factory :section do
  trait :with_components do
    after(:build) do |s|
      # Modify this to create components of different types if you want to
      s.components = [create(:component)]
    end
  end
end

# Rspec
subject { build(:section, :with_components) }
```

#### Couple of more things

This association in your `Component` model looks fishy:

```
belongs_to :section,
  class_name: 'Component',
  foreign_key: :section_id,
  optional: true
```

- Are you sure you want to link a `Component` instance to another `Component` instance?
- And while doing that, you want to use foreign key `:section_id` instead of conventional `component_id`?

You already have a model `Section` in your application. It might cause confusions. See below:

```
component = Component.first
component.section
 => #<Component id: 10001>      # I would expect it to be a `Section` instance looking at the association name
```

Comment: I have a trait called section in my component factory so that's why I used `subject! { build(:component, :section) }`. Would that affect the association for the spec? For the association in my models, a `Component` can be a Section or EssentialQuestion, etc. and a Section can contain `Component`s. Does that work?

Comment: Basic problem is that you are building a `Component` while you need a `Section` in your rspecs.